# AT&T U-Verse modem/router to router is very slow

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I have an [ASUS RT-N66U](http://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTN66U/) router behind the AT&T U-Verse supplied 2wire modem/router on a 24Mbps connection.  The ASUS is behind the U-Verse 2wire modem, as I want to use OpenDNS and wireless N and not just the built in 802.11b/g capabilities of the 2wire.

Recently, all connections through the ASUS router have become extremely slow; kess than 2Mbps. If I connect any device to the 2wire, the speed is exactly what it should be.

Moved the ASUS about two feet away, which did not change the slowness. I don’t have any disabled ports and this configuration used to work just fine until we moved.

Comment: The question is unclear as asked. Are you saying that WIRELESS connections are running at 2Mbps? Perhaps we need a network diagram here.

Comment: Could be something causing interference near the Asus router, have you tried moving the device to another location and testing the MBps?

Comment: Did you turn off the wireless on the AT&T U-Verse router?  It might be causing interference.  You should also try a *wired* connection to the Asus router.  If it's still slow, then wireless isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you review the configuration settings of the 2wire device. If it is not in [Bridge mode,](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bridge%20mode%22%202wire) then call ATT to have them set it in Bridge mode (which often only they can do). This will also disable wireless coming from the 2Wire, which is a goodness.

[Bridge mode](http://www.workbooth.info/docs/bridged.htm) has nothing to do with the distance between the 2Wire 'Gateway' device and your ASUS router. [Bridge mode](http://arris.force.com/consumers/articles/General_FAQs/Bridge-Mode-vs-Routed-Subnet) is a configuration which tells the 2Wire not to try to double-route the traffic, so it functions as only a codec device (the digital equivalent of 'modem').

This means the underpowered (IMHO) 2Wire is no longer trying to route. You have a perfectly capable ASUS router, let it do the routing.

This also avoids the dreaded '[Double NAT](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/xbox_one_support/f/4267/t/1667088.aspx)', killer of fast performance.

Comment: When I was doing research, I came across that suggestion and I have moved it about two feet away. Sadly, the tests came back with the same results.